# Using struct to create detail view controller from tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

First of all, I am a beginner! So it's a bit complicated, but basically I am trying to create a separate view controller that displays information held in a `struct/string` with objects. I am making a directory. I have two controllers, one for the `tableView` (called `DirectoryTableViewController`) and one for the detail view (called `FacultyViewController`) and then I have a swift file (called People) that has manages the String. 
I am eventually going to add name, phone, email and an image to the `String`, but for now I am just doing the names.

My problem is that it is working and I need some pointers. Thanks!!

Here is my DirectoryTableView:

```
import UIKit

struct peoples {
  var teacherString: String!
  var image: UIImage!
}

class DirectoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
  var array : [People]!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(array)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }


  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("directoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let person = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = person.teacherString



    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  }
}
```

Here is my NewViewController:

```
import UIKit
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var emailTextTield: UITextField!
  var array : [People] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func crateObjectButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let object = People(name: nameTextField.text! , phone: phoneTextField.text!, email: emailTextTield.text!)
    array.append(object)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("TeacherData", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TeacherData" {
        let dvc =  segue.destinationViewController as? DirectoryTableViewController
        dvc!.array = array

    }
  }
}
```

Here is People.swift (model):

```
import Foundation

class People {
  var name : String
  var phone: String
  var email: String

  init(name: String, phone: String, email: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
    self.email = email
  }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Not getting your question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question , you have to make a model

import Foundation

```
class People {
    var name : String
    var phone: String
    var email: String

    init(name: String, phone: String, email: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
    self.email = email
    }
}
```

and make a view controller from where you gather all these details for eg: like this

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextTield: UITextField!
    var array : [People] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func crateObjectButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let object = People(name: nameTextField.text! , phone: phoneTextField.text!, email: ageTextTield.text!)
        array.append(object)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("TeacherData", sender: self)  
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TeacherData" {
            let dvc =  segue.destinationViewController as? TableviewController
               dvc!.array = array

        }
    }
}
```

and this segue take you to the tableviewcontroller where in viewdidLoad i am printing the array of teachers.

```
import UIKit
class TableviewController: UITableViewController {
    var array : [People]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(array)
    }
}
```

and you go to the deatil view controller of a selected teacher by using this method:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        object =  array![indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier("yourdetailviewcontrollersegue", sender: self) 
    }
```

Comment: i understand this code, but I am very confused where to add it. Should I replace my current code with this or just add it?

Comment: you can replace your code if you find this easy to understand , but for more details. 1) make a model 2) make a view controller so that you can accept the teachers details in that VC and 3) finally make a tableviewcontroller so that you can list down the entries .. hope you got it

Comment: sorry for being such a beginner, i'm still learning. when you refer to making a model, do you mean making a separate swift file to refer to?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the code in my question (above). I am getting an error "Value of type 'People' has no member 'teacher String" on the line of code      var array : [People]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(array)
    } in the DirectoryTableViewController

Comment: I think because you have not declared the teacher String in your model, Can you share your code for better understanding of your problem..

Comment: I updated the new code to my original question ^ above.

Comment: this is your area of problem                                                                           let person = array[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = person.teacherString //you are acessing teacher string which is not the part of  **var array : [People]!**   Use **cell.textLabel!.text = person. name** or  **cell.textLabel!.text = person. phone** or  **cell.textLabel!.text = person. email**